# Can't delete files from remote Buffalo drive, "Permission Denied"

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, smb

There are several files on a remote Buffalo drive that I can't delete. I'm using a Mac (OSX 10.9.5) and Finder reports the drive's filesystem as "SMB (NTFS)".

I have tried from the GUI and from Terminal, but I always get "Permission Denied":

```
Web$ rm -f LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
rm: LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot: Permission denied
```

Even with "sudo":

```
Web$ sudo rm -f LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot 
Password:
rm: LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot: Permission denied
```

Here is a directory listing:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Web  staff    4096 Jun 26  2014 ._LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Web  staff    4096 Jun 26  2014 ._LigatureSymbols-2.11.otf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Web  staff    4096 Jun 26  2014 ._LigatureSymbols-2.11.svg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Web  staff    4096 Jun 26  2014 ._LigatureSymbols-2.11.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Web  staff    4096 Jun 26  2014 ._LigatureSymbols-2.11.woff
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff   83542 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff   82468 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.otf
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff  201950 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.svg
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff   83340 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff   62636 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.woff
drwxrwxrwx  2 Web  staff   16384 Mar  5 08:59 _notes
```

I am logged in as "Web", so it seems that I am the owner. It also seems that I have full permission (read, write, execute).

I tried looking for flags (such as "immutable") that might prevent deletion, but there don't seem to be any:

```
Web$ ls -leO
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff  -  83542 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff  -  82468 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.otf
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff  - 201950 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.svg
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff  -  83340 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Web  staff  -  62636 Jan 30  2013 LigatureSymbols-2.11.woff
drwxrwxrwx  2 Web  staff  -  16384 Mar  5 08:59 _notes
```

I tried removing the "immutable" flag, even though it doesn't seem to be set, but to no avail:

```
Web$ chflags nouchg LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
Web$ rm -f LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
rm: LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot: Permission denied
```

I notice some "extended attributes" (@) on the files, but nothing that would obviously prevent deletion:

```
com.apple.ResourceFork     286 
com.apple.quarantine        42 
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       137
```

And I can't seem to remove these attributes either:

```
Web$ xattr -c LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot'
```

Not even with "sudo":

```
Web$ sudo xattr -c LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot
Password:
xattr: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot'
```

How can I remove these files from the drive?

---

Edit:
Is there any tool or method to "force delete" files without regard for permission?

Comment: Is it possible that the "Web" user is not the same "Web" user to which I'm logged in? Could it be a different (non non-existent) user that had the same name?

Comment: `sudo` should take care of that. But as the files are not local: did you restart the Buffalo drive?

Comment: Have you tried taking ownership of the files first?

Comment: @patrix Thanks for the suggestion. I just restarted the drive and I still get "permission denied" when trying to delete those files.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I am logged in as "Web", which appears to be the owner of the files. Could I be mistaken?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the drive using cifs:// instead of smb://

Comment: @Hefewe1zen How do I do that? I tried connecting to `cifs://path-to-the-drive/` and Finder now reports the filesystem as "SMB (Other)". I am still unable to delete the files.